# RPi pin state on startup not default

Tags: gpio

I have 2 Raspberry Pis a model 3B+ and a model 2.  Both are loaded with identical software (I cloned the SD card using the raspberry SD card copier).  They are running PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"

When I reboot and run raspi-gpio get the 3B returns GPIO pins 1 to 8 as inputs at level 0.  The Pi 2 returns pins 1 to 8 as inputs at level 1 (except from pin 4 which for some reason is at level 0).

I am expecting pins 1 to 8 to be at level 1 on both devices as per the documentation.  Some of the other pins on the Pi 3 are at level 1.

The only thing plugged into the GPIO pins is a normally open push button between physical pins 5 and 6 on the Pi 2.

Any thoughts

```
For the Pi2 (which is working) 
pi@raspberrypi: ~
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspi-gpio get 1-8
GPIO 1: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 2: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 3: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 4: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 5: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 6: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
```

```
The config file is
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
enable_uart=0
dtoverlay=w1-gpio

#shutdown button code
dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown
```

For the Pi3

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspi-gpio get 1-8
GPIO 1: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 2: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 3: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 4: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 5: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 6: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 7: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 8: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
```

```
The config file is
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
enable_uart=0
dtoverlay=w1-gpio

#shutdown button code
dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown
```

Comment: Post the output of `raspi-gpio get 1-8` as well as contents of `config,txt`

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hoping the default OS sets the GPIOs how you require, why not specifically set the GPIOs state in config.txt:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#gpio-control

Answer (score 0):

Your Raspberry Pi 3B+ is faulty.  There is no way GPIO 2/3 (pins 3/5) report as low inputs with nothing attached.  They have hardwired pulls to 3V3 fitted.

Answer (score 0):

For the Pi2 pin 4 is level 0 because you have enabled `w1-gpio` Onewire interface.

I can only conclude the Pi3 is dead if nothing is connected. Pins 2,3 have 1.8kΩ pullup - the ONLY way these could be low is if they were shorted to Gnd.

Comment: Thank you.  I think the GPIO pins are shorted to ground.  I'm running DS18B20 temperature sensors on GPIO 4.  When connected to the Pi 3 these have 0 volts on the signal line.  When I disconnect the line from GPio 4 these revert to 3.3 V.  Just bought a new Pi 4.  The Pi 3 is running OK, just he GPIO seems suspect.